# What does this shutoff switch in a 100 year old house control? Located in plaster wall near top of basment steps

Tags: electrical, basement, switch, shutoff

This shutoff switch, near the top of the basement steps in an old home confounds us.
[image]

Comment: Might be a very old electrical switch. For a very old basement light, say, or one that is no longer connected.

Comment: Looks like an old light switch to me.

Comment: It releases the shackled clowns from the abandoned lunatic asylum in the basement. Don't touch it!!

Comment: I had one like this in the foyer of my 110 year old house. Played with it for weeks but never saw anything go on or off. Eventually I got a letter from a woman in Germany that said "Hör auf damit!"

Comment: I think it's an on/off switch for an old doorbell.

Comment: Is A.I. Breveleri an anagram for Steven Wright?

Comment: There are no 'A's' in Steven Wright. So, it can't be an anagram. 

Comment: Steven Wright is my illegitimate father. He never told me who my mother was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's an on/off switch that as far as you can tell controls nothing, I'd start by pulling the switch away from the wall and attempting to figure out where the wiring goes and to what if any fusebox it connects to.