# Electricity power off in some bed rooms and back again regularly each night but breakers are still on

Tags: electrical

Electricity power is off in some bed rooms regularly each night for about 20-60 minutes. Switches are still on. Our neighbors do not have this problem. I am not sure what causes this problem. Thanks!

Comment: What country are you in?  Have you explored to narrow down if everything affected is on one circuit breaker or multiple circuit breakers?  If you are USA, that is an important first step, it tells you whether the problem is the wiring in your house, the breaker panel or even possibly a power company issue.

Comment: Whichever circuit is doing this, I would move with all haste to install an AFCI breaker there.  If arcing is involved, this can burn your house down.

Comment: Do you live anywhere near this guy https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/121504/45091 ?

Comment: I live in Louisiana State. We replaced main breaker yesterday but the problem is still on but this time it is slightly different from before, even more problems than before.

Comment: It may not be breaker's problem as no power in multiple bed rooms simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

This can be every thing from a failing supply to the home, knocking out 1 leg to a daisy chained set of outlets that has a bad connection.  First I would see if the problem is on multiple breakers if it is all odd or all even breakers get the power company involved because this would indicate a serious problem with your service. If it is only 1 breaker that the problem is associated with it can be a weak connection at the breaker but more likely in my experience is a daisy chained outlet that uses back stabs is failing or a loose wire nut / broken wire when the connection gets hot it opens. This is also a concern as there is usually arcing. If this is the case it can usually be traced to 1 outlet or junction in a box with an outlet or switch. When the power goes out work towards the service panel looking for the last place there is power. Once the first no power outlet is found the problem will be there or the outlet before it. With the breaker off pull the outlet and inspect the connections, if back stabs are used pulling the outlet can at times temporally fix the problem until a large load causes it to start failing again. I recommend replacing outlets that have had this issue because you don't know how much damage occoured inside. I use the screw connectors on outlets and switches because I have repaired hundreds of failed backstab outlets and switches over the years.

Comment: We found main breaker had a bad connection and replaced it. However the problem is still on but slightly different from before. Before it occurred about 2-3:00 AM but this time it was 6:00 in the morning. Also few more outlets have the problem. If this is mainly related to outlets, we may just replace outlets that have the problem. Your answer is very much appreciated and I am trying to understand each word of you.

Comment: It may not be breaker's problem as no power in 3 bed rooms simultaneously.